# Python generator compute and store in background

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, generator

I have a python generator which goes through a list of files and processes the data inside one by one. **The order is important as I need the result from the previous file to calculate the next file** so it's not an embarrassingly parallel task. When each file is processed I spit the data out of the generator to start the main calculation. I'm wondering if its possible to keep the generator running in the background and 'cache' the results although I don't have too much experience with this topic.

My code looks something like this -

```
for processedData in myGenerator():
    bigCalculation(processedData)
```

and I'm looking for something like this -

```
for processedData in cleverParallelFunction(myGenerator()):
    bigCalculation(processedData)
```

As a note the processedData is of reasonable size (a few GB) and the processing time is on the order of of reading from file time. I'm curious if multiprocessing is even helpful here as it sending data down the pipe might take quite some time as well but I'm not sure!

Any help would be really appreciated here!

Comment: ‘multiprocessing’ may help here. Look into a ‘Pool’. It’s map method takes an iterable which is where your generator could fit in.

Comment: I'm unsure if pool is the correct choice here as in order to calculate the next step of the generator I need results from the previous one

Comment: Oh, you didn't say that before. It currently looks like `myGenerator()` produces a sequence of `processedData` which needs to be passed into `bigCalculation()`. You didn't say anything about the result of `bigCalculation()` being needed back in `myGenerator()`.

Comment: Just to be 100% clear no result from the `bigCalculation()` is used in the calculation of the generator. It's just that the generator has a lot of state and depends on previous invocations to be able to calculate the next method. I don't think map can be used in this case as it requires the function it calls to be basically stateless.

Comment: Yes, the function it calls only gets to see the parameter passed, which in this case is implicitly ‘processedData’. The other parameter to map is an iterable for which you would use your generator. Perhaps you need to try this with dummy data and  functions.